# Don't have news about my eTA process, what should I do?

Tags: air-travel, canada, eta, mexican-citizens, tourism

I started my eTA process last Wednesday and I still don't know if it has been approved or denied. I haven't heard anything from the IRCC either, all I got from them was an email that I received that same Wednesday, which stated that my process was "under review", but I haven't got any update since then, and it's almost been a full week.

I don't know if this is a normal situation due to the global pandemic we are facing right now, if so, is anyone in the same situation as me? Should I ask for an enquiry or fill out their "Web Form"? Any information will be useful, thank you for reading!!

Comment: https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1085&top=16

Comment: Just to be sure, did you used the official governmental website or one of the many scammer sites?